# Find upper Hessenberg by Householder transformation

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra

I have a matrix that looks like this:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
  \epsilon & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \end{pmatrix}
$$

Compute a Householder transformation so that the matrix becomes an Upper Hessenberg.

Is there any special property of this matrix that I can use (since there is a matrix element that is a variable)?

I tried to find vector $u$ but it did not work out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
Q=I-\frac{2}{2\epsilon^2}
\begin{pmatrix}0\\-\epsilon\\0\\\epsilon\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}0\\-\epsilon\\0\\\epsilon\end{pmatrix}^T
=
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&1\\
0&0&1&0\\
0&1&0&0
\end{pmatrix}\;,\quad
QA=\begin{pmatrix}
\color{red}0&\color{red}1&\color{red}0&\color{red}0\\
\color{red}\epsilon&\color{red}0&\color{red}0&\color{red}0\\
0&\color{red}0&\color{red}0&\color{red}1\\
0&0&\color{red}1&\color{red}0
\end{pmatrix}\;.
$$

Comment: from where did you get the vector $v$?

Comment: You want to transform $x=[0,0,0,\epsilon]^T$ to $y=[0,\epsilon,0,0]^T$, hence $u$ in $Q=I-2uu^T$ is given by $u=(x-y)/\|x-y\|_2=[0,-\epsilon,0,\epsilon]^T/(2\epsilon)^{1/2}$.

Comment: thanks, that really helped!